# Save name with grouped_options_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with `grouped_options_for_select`.
My categories are correctly add in my database but the names are not save when i return on my form.

```
<% categories = {
      'Finances'      => [['Note de frais', 3], ['Devis', 5]],
      'Marketing' => [['Mailing', 4], ['Réseaux Sociaux',6]]
 } %>

<%= f.select :category_ids, grouped_options_for_select(categories), {}, { multiple: true, class: "selectize" } %>
```

I would like to have the same result as this :

```
<%= f.select :category_ids, Category.all.pluck(:name, :id), {}, {multiple: true, class:"selectize"}%>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: it's not clear what is your problem, you have a form that when you load an edit the selected option doesn't comes by default selected? is that the problem?

Comment: Hello ! The problem with my solution 1 is after sending the form.
When i come back on the edit page. I do not see the categories i selected when sending my form.

In my solution 1 i miss something like "pluck(:name,:id)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the `grouped_options_for_select` you can pass a parameter for `selected_key`, so you can specify the one that is selected when you load the view, so you just have to pass the value there

```
<%= f.select :category_ids, grouped_options_for_select(categories, selected_key: @record.category_id), {}, { multiple: true, class: "selectize" } %>
```

Comment: OK thanks a lot ! Your answer will help me better understand the rails documentation ! I did not understand how to use the grouped_options correctly.

Final solution :
<%= f.select :category_ids, grouped_options_for_select(categories, @software.category_ids), {}, {multiple: true, class: "selectize"} %>